# Compare files when they equal the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am comparing 2 txt files that outputs another txt file if there is a difference. (this is working fine)

```
with open('master.txt','r') as masterfile:
    with open('file','r') as usedfile:
        difference = set(masterfile).difference(usedfile)

with open('text3.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in difference:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Is there a way where if both files equal the same then add the words ‘ALL GOOD’ in the 3rd txt file (test3.txt) currently it just creates a blank file.

Comment: `’` is not a valid inverted comma. Beyond that, I don't really undersrtand what you're asking

Comment: Hi Roganjosh, basically what trying to say is that when both 2 files that i am comparing has the same data then i want the 3rd txt file to include the word 'all good'

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `difference` has value else write `"ALL GOOD"`

**Ex:**

```
with open('master.txt','r') as masterfile:
    with open('file','r') as usedfile:
        difference = set(masterfile).difference(usedfile)

with open('text3.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    if difference:
        for line in difference:
            file_out.write(line)
    else:
        file_out.write('ALL GOOD')
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, that works when both file is the same, however when there is a difference in those 2 files it still includes the word 'ALL GOOD ' whereas i want to only show the difference in the 3rd file when there is a difference. if that make sense.

Comment: Looks like you need `symmetric_difference` try `difference = set(masterfile).symmetric_difference(usedfile)`

Comment: thanks for getting back, i add the snippet of code above but it is still including the word 'ALL GOOD'. any other ideas?

Comment: Can you please post the modified code in the question?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, i have modified the code in question. thanks